# Node-Webkit Iframe Not Displaying Internet Browser

Tags: node.js, iframe, node-webkit

Maybe I installed something incorrectly or something, but no matter what I try, I can't get a browser window to display in an iframe. I copy-pasted code from an example I found into the main page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>You should be able to see Google in an iframe below:</b>
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com" style="width: 80%;" nwdisable nwfaketop>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also copy-pasted the JSON file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "main": "main.html",
  "window": {
    "width": 600,
    "height": 400,
    "position": "center",
    "title": "Test",
    "resizable": true
  }
}
```

When I run the code with "C:\node-webkit\nw.exe ." from the command line, I get "You should be able to see Google in an iframe below:" with an empty box below it.

Also, I'm on Windows. Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm able to run all of the sample apps [here](https://github.com/zcbenz/nw-sample-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to load an HTTPS site within an HTTP window.